# Просчитать дальше последовательность

Tags: notepad++

Нужно в огромном массиве нотепадом дальше просчитать числа, то есть продолжить нумерацию, что бы вручную не писать все числа.

```
'59' => 'text',
'60' => 'text',
'61' => 'text',
'62' => 'text', // <-- отсюда например
'62' => 'text',
'62' => 'text',
'62' => 'text',
'62' => 'text',
'62' => 'text',
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зажав клавишу `alt` выделите столбец с цифрами

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выберите `правка -> генератор столбца` или `alt+C`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

введите нужные параметры

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

окончательный результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Это шикарно!